# Emulate at-least-once from Kafka Streams with regular `kafka-clients`

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to emulate the at-least-once guarantees that the following Kafka Streams code provides:

```
streamsBuilder.stream("topic-from").to("topic-to")
```

using `poll`, `send` and `commitAsync` from `kafka-clients`. This must be possible since Kafka Streams uses `kafka-clients` under the hood.

As far as I understand, Kafka Streams guarantees that offsets for "topic-from" are only committed when all messages that are published on "topic-to" are acknowledged by the broker(s).

```
┌─────────────────┐               ┌────┐               ┌─────────────────┐
│                 ├─poll(100 ms)─▶│    │─────send─────▶│                 │
│                 │               │    │               │                 │
│                 │               │    │               │                 │
│   topic-from    │               │    │               │    topic-to     │
│                 │               │    │               │                 │
│                 │               │    │               │                 │
│                 │◀─commitAsync──│    │◀─────ack──────┤                 │
└─────────────────┘               └────┘               └─────────────────┘
```

My plan was to collect each acknowledgement (for each message produced) into one big `CompletableFuture` (by using the `Callback`-parameter of the `send` function) and committing offsets when that completes.

I also think I need to track each offset for each "batch" consumed separately because I need to avoid committing offsets for batch 2 when sending messages for batch 1 has not been completed/acknowledged yet (and might fail).

This sounds rather complicated, so I was wondering if there was an easier way to implement this (pretty common) use case?

Comment: Well, you could look at the Kafka source code to see how it is done in Streams

Comment: Any idea where I can find this? Had a look before I asked but it is a pretty intimidating code base (at least to me).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where in the code to point to. Is there a particular reason you cannot at least use the Processor API rather than producer/consumer?

Comment: I want to show my team what they would be getting for "free" with Kafka Streams.

Comment: I mean, you can find the examples of how you can configure the delivery semantics here - https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-clients-at-most-once-at-least-once-exactly-o  alternatively, the MirrorMaker1 code does exactly what you're asking when configured between a single cluster https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/MirrorMaker.scala

Comment: Sure! Unfortunately, these examples are using `commitSync`, which I hope to avoid (why should processing be blocked on committing)?

Comment: Otherwise you don't get at least once delivery, probably